# Coupon Collector with different probabilities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I recently came across the following problem:

> Bonnie wants to collect 2 coupons. Each box costs 10\$, and she doesn't know which coupon will be inside before she opens it. The probability of getting A is $\frac{1}{3}$ while that of coupon B has $\frac{2}{3}$.

I need to find the expected number of coupons she needs to buy before she can get both coupons, as well as how much she would spend. I solved it the following way:

$X = X_1 + X_2$ where $X_1$ is the first coupon and $X_2$ is the second coupon she buys.
I then divided this into two cases:
X = Geom(1) + Geom(2/3) = 3/2
X = Geom(1) + Geom(1/3) = 4

However, I don't know how to proceed from here... I thought that i would add these two cases together and find the average, but that sounds like purely wrong intuition. How need I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label the four possible states according to which coupons Bonnie has. If $i\subset\{A,B\}$ let $E[i]$ denote the expected number of purchases she'll need to complete her set.

Now, $E[A]=\frac 32$:  Imagine that Bonnie puchases a new coupon. With $\frac 23$ probability she has completed her set in one shot.  With $\frac 13$ probability she gets $A$ again and has to repeat the exercise (so her expected time along this path is $E[A]+1$.  Thus $$E[A]=\frac 23\,1+\frac 13 (E[A]+1)$$ which quickly implies $E[A]=\frac 32$.

Similarly, $E[B]= 3$

We want $E[\emptyset]$.  But look at the first purchase.  As before we see that $$E[\emptyset]=\frac 13\,(E[A]+1)\;+\;\frac 23 \,(E[B]+1)= \frac 72$$